# Error when trying to see Executions for Standard Reports in Integration Services Catalog through SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSMS I am trying to get to the Reports Executions or Validations Screen for any package within the Integration Services Catalog by right clicking on any package->Reports-> Standard Reports->All Executions

But there seems to be some issue when I do that and get the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing. (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms)
>
> The definition of the report '' is invalid. (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common)
>
> An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘2011’. (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common)

We have several systems that seem to be having this error, for me it's happening on my Laptop and not on my Desktop but others are having this issue on Desktops as well which tends me to believe this has something to do with SSMS back-end which is causing this like .NET framework or something. But then I verified the .NET framework versions,  OS versions,SQL Server Management Studio versions all seem to be the same as well so I am not sure what's the cause and how can I resolve this. I have tried uninstalling and installing .NET Framework and SSMS and that didn't work.

Having this issue with different SSMS versions and different .NET versions (including latest one).

Can someone please give some suggestions on resolving this.

Comment: Is adequate access granted? If not admin access, should have ssis_logreader or 2016 or datareader access to folders in Integration services catalog.

Comment: If access is good, restart IIS.

Comment: This is not an access problem for viewing because some of us are able to see it and some of us aren't and I even gave sysadmin to a user temporarily to prove that it's not an access issue and they still had the same issue